# Blazor WebAssembly Role-based Authorization - won't recognize JWT roles with Keycloak

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, authorization, blazor, keycloak

I'm having an issue with a Blazor WebAssembly app, and Keycloak. What's basically hapenning is, the `<AuthorizeView>` tags don't work when I specify roles with `<AuthorizeView Roles="Role">`.
I have already configured Keycloak so the roles are brought into the JWT as first level objects, like so (corroborated with jwt.io):

```json
{
  "...": "..."
  "role": "role1"
  "role": "role2"
  "role": "role3"
  "...": "..."
}
```

this should in theory allow Blazor to detect the role claims to apply them in razor pages, but it's not working. I tried several methods but I can't get this role detection working, it always falls back to `<NotAuthorized>`'s contents, like this test over here:

```html
<AuthorizeView Context="QuestionsManagement" Roles="Recruiter">
   <Authorized>
      <li class="nav-item px-3">
         <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/selection-processes" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
            <span class="oi oi-book" aria-hidden="true"></span> Manage Questions
         </NavLink>
      </li>
   </Authorized>
   <NotAuthorized>
      <li class="nav-item px-3">
         <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/selection-processes" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
            <span class="oi oi-book" aria-hidden="true"></span> Test not authorized
         </NavLink>
      </li>
   </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

What should I be paying attention to? What could be missing/misconfigured?

Comment: Have you added `CascadingAuthenticationState` component?

Comment: Sorry, where should I see if I have added that component? The provided razor code is working inside `NavMenu.razor`

Comment: It should wrap around everything inside `App.razor` like `<CascadingAuthenticationState>    <Router ...>    ...   
 </Router> 
   </CascadingAuthenticationState>`

Comment: Btw, are the roles returned in the access token or in the id token?

Comment: Yes, this is how App.razor looks, it did not stray far from the stock Blazor template: https://pastecode.io/s/rucecoxz
This is how my JWT currently looks (with "sensitive" info censored):
https://pastebin.com/tzvCt7Xb

Comment: Roles are returned in the access token I believe, I take that from jwt.io after pasting the bearer token that gets saved to local storage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247856/discussion-between-dimitris-maragkos-and-maxi-jabase).